# Powershell - Find all USB Gamepads

Tags: powershell, windows-10

In Windows 10, If I go to Control Panel --> Devices and Printers the top row shows me "devices" In my case these include "USB Gamepad", "2.4G Mouse" etc

How can I query this list of devices using Powershell? I want to check if a device called "USB Gamepad" is connected to the PC.

So far I have gone via the device manager route as follows but have been unable to get the info I need:

```
$devs = Get-PnPDevice -Class HIDClass | where { $_.HardwareID.Contains("HID_DEVICE_SYSTEM_GAME") }

foreach ($d in $devs){
    echo $d.FriendlyName
    echo $d.DeviceID
    echo $d.HardwareID
    echo $d.Name
    echo $d.Class
    echo ""
    echo ""
}
```

It looks like I may be able to do something with the information in the registry @ `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\MediaProperties\PrivateProperties\Joystick`

Comment: Putting this here separate from my answer.  Point of note: --- The accepted best practice is note is: --- Single quotes for simple string, double for variable expansion, and other multi-quoted use cases.  --- echo (aka alias for Write-Host) is not needed for simple screen output. Output to the screen is the PowerShell default unless you tell it otherwise. --- Write-Host is only needed in a few use cases.  --- 1 - Colorizewd screen text output  --- 2 - Some formatting cases. --- But the choice is always up to the individual since we all have our own styles and habits.

Answer (score 0):

This...

```
Get-PnPDevice -Class HIDClass | 
where { $_.HardwareID.Contains("HID_DEVICE_SYSTEM_GAME") }
```

... if not syntactically correct and should be this...

```
... 
where { $PSItem.HardwareID -Contains ...}
```

There is not dot notation for comparison operators.

I would refactor that line to this...

```
Clear-Host
Get-PnPDevice -Class HIDClass | 
ForEach {
    $PSItem | 
    Where-Object {$PSItem.HardwareID -match 'HID_DEVICE'} | 
    Select-Object -Property FriendlyName, DeviceID, HardwareID, Name, Class
    "`n`n"
} 
# Results
<#
...
FriendlyName : HID-compliant consumer control device
DeviceID     : HID\VID_17A0&PID_0305&MI_03\B&345E789C&0&0000
HardwareID   : {HID\VID_17A0&PID_0305&REV_0207&MI_03, HID\VID_17A0&PID_0305&MI_03, HID\VID_17A0&UP:000C_U:0001, HID_DEVICE_SYSTEM_CONSUMER, 
               HID_DEVICE_UP:000C_U:0001, HID_DEVICE}
Name         : HID-compliant consumer control device
Class        : HIDClass
...
#>
```